# Select string starting with numbers in R

Tags: r

This is very simple yet I cannot get it 100% right!

I have column of data that looks like this:

```
"424343 Amsterdam center" 
"343423 London 42 ......"
"3434   Prague ........." 
"343345 Bratislava ...."
"! last entry ..... 25.08.2014..."
"Berlin"
...
...
```

I would like to replace all rows starting with letter with empty string ""

I have tried:

```
dataframe$column[grepl("(^[A-Z]+).*",dataframe$column)] <- ""
```

I'm still getting the rows like these .... `"! last entry ..... 25.08.2014..."`

Desired output:

```
 "424343 Amsterdam center" 
 "343423 London 42 ......"
 "3434   Prague ........." 
 "343345 Bratislava ...."
 ""
 ""
...
...
```

Comment: The reason you got a warning message was that the column was a factor and you tried to replace an elemment with a value that was not in the list of levels. You should have used either stringsAsFactors=FALSE or first converted to character mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can look just for strings starting with at least one number and take all non matching results (using `!`), e.g.:

```
!grepl("^[[:digit:]]+", text)
```

In your example:

```
dataframe$column[!grepl("^[[:digit:]]+",dataframe$column)] <- ""
```

Comment: Could there be an alternative for this using starts_with from stringr?

Answer (score 3):

This was my strategy for building what I suspect was causing problems for the OP:

```
> inp <- scan(what="")
1: "424343 Amsterdam center" 
2: "343423 London 42 ......"
3: "3434   Prague ........." 
4: "343345 Bratislava ...."
5: "! last entry ..... 25.08.2014..."
6: "Berlin"
7: 

dat <- data.frame(inp=inp)
```

And what I suspect he was seeing:

```
> dat$inp[grepl("(^[A-Z]+).*",dat$inp)] <- ""
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, grepl("(^[A-Z]+).*", dat$inp), value = c(5L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
> dat
                               inp
1          424343 Amsterdam center
2          343423 London 42 ......
3          3434   Prague .........
4           343345 Bratislava ....
5 ! last entry ..... 25.08.2014...
6                             <NA>
```

So the approach I was suggesting in my comment was one of two possibilities:

```
dat <- data.frame(inp=inp, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)  # option 1
dat$inp <- as.character(dat$inp)         # convert factor to character
```

Then the OP's code works as he expected:

```
> dat$inp[grepl("(^[A-Z]+).*",dat$inp)] <- ""
> dat
                               inp
1          424343 Amsterdam center
2          343423 London 42 ......
3          3434   Prague .........
4           343345 Bratislava ....
5 ! last entry ..... 25.08.2014...
6
```

Comment: (+1) Thank you.  I deleted mine because I don't really like submitting answers to questions that aren't clear/are missing important info.

Comment: Sir, you have my deep respect. Your answers set a high standard.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
dataframe$column[grepl("^[^0-9]",dataframe$column)] <- ""
```